# report server (ssrs): how to handle long names on vertical axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, power-bi-report-server

I have a chart built in Report Builder (MS Reporting Services), where vertical axe is categorical.
Label names of categorical axe is very long.
Is it possible to shrink the length of names for first 10 symbols and show full names when mouse coursor is over the names?

[image: Example of chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible natively in SSRS but you might be able to get an acceptable compromise.

First click on the chart, so the config pane opens, click on your category group and then edit the label property to something like this

```
=LEFT(Fields!Caption.Value, 10)
```

(Caption is the name of the field containing the label that appears on the Y axis in my case)

[image]

Now that you have the shortened name showing you need to show the full name somewhere. Unfortunately, the group labels do not support tooltips but chart series do.

Click anywhere on the bar (but not on the data label) and then set the tooltip property to something like

```
=Fields!Caption.Value & " " & Fields!Amount.Value
```

[image]

When we run the report and hover the mouse over the 3rd green bar, we get the following...

[image]

Comment: Alan, thank you very much. Your solution worked great. The only thing, I needed to make the second step for both the sides of the bar since left side of the bar is very small.